# App runs with --add-modules=java.se.ee in Eclipse but not on command line

Tags: java, java-9

I'm using Java 9-ea to both run an [app](https://github.com/openrocket/openrocket) built in Eclipse and to run a Ant-built jar of the same app on the commend line. In Eclipse everything works if I pass the `--permit-illegal-access --add-modules=java.se.ee` VM args but if I pass the same on the command line:

```
java --add-modules=java.se.ee --permit-illegal-access -jar swing/build/jar/OpenRocket.jar
```

things fail at runtime:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Error starting OpenRocket
    at net.sf.openrocket.startup.jij.JarInJarStarter.runMain(JarInJarStarter.java:40)
    at net.sf.openrocket.startup.OpenRocket.main(OpenRocket.java:36)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:563)
    at net.sf.openrocket.startup.jij.JarInJarStarter.runMain(JarInJarStarter.java:38)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.invokeAndWait(EventQueue.java:1323)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.invokeAndWait(EventQueue.java:1298)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait(SwingUtilities.java:1475)
    at net.sf.openrocket.startup.SwingStartup.main(SwingStartup.java:76)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: com.google.common.util.concurrent.ExecutionError: com.google.common.util.concurrent.ExecutionError: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/script/ScriptEngineFactory
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.get(LocalCache.java:2212)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.get(LocalCache.java:4053)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.getOrLoad(LocalCache.java:4057)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalLoadingCache.get(LocalCache.java:4986)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalLoadingCache.getUnchecked(LocalCache.java:4992)
    at com.google.inject.internal.FailableCache.get(FailableCache.java:48)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjectorStore.get(ConstructorInjectorStore.java:50)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorBindingImpl.initialize(ConstructorBindingImpl.java:138)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.initializeJitBinding(InjectorImpl.java:550)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.createJustInTimeBinding(InjectorImpl.java:887)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.createJustInTimeBindingRecursive(InjectorImpl.java:808)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getJustInTimeBinding(InjectorImpl.java:285)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getBindingOrThrow(InjectorImpl.java:217)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getInternalFactory(InjectorImpl.java:893)
    at com.google.inject.internal.FactoryProxy.notify(FactoryProxy.java:46)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProcessedBindingData.runCreationListeners(ProcessedBindingData.java:50)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator.initializeStatically(InternalInjectorCreator.java:134)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator.build(InternalInjectorCreator.java:107)
    at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:99)
    at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:73)
    at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:62)
    at net.sf.openrocket.startup.SwingStartup.runInEDT(SwingStartup.java:143)
    at net.sf.openrocket.startup.SwingStartup.access$000(SwingStartup.java:43)
    at net.sf.openrocket.startup.SwingStartup$1.run(SwingStartup.java:79)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:303)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:759)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:712)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:706)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:88)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:729)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:199)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
Caused by: com.google.common.util.concurrent.ExecutionError: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/script/ScriptEngineFactory
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.get(LocalCache.java:2212)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.get(LocalCache.java:4053)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.getOrLoad(LocalCache.java:4057)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalLoadingCache.get(LocalCache.java:4986)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalLoadingCache.getUnchecked(LocalCache.java:4992)
    at com.google.inject.internal.FailableCache.get(FailableCache.java:48)
    at com.google.inject.internal.MembersInjectorStore.get(MembersInjectorStore.java:68)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjectorStore.createConstructor(ConstructorInjectorStore.java:75)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjectorStore.access$000(ConstructorInjectorStore.java:29)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjectorStore$1.create(ConstructorInjectorStore.java:37)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjectorStore$1.create(ConstructorInjectorStore.java:33)
    at com.google.inject.internal.FailableCache$1.load(FailableCache.java:37)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LoadingValueReference.loadFuture(LocalCache.java:3628)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.loadSync(LocalCache.java:2336)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.lockedGetOrLoad(LocalCache.java:2295)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.get(LocalCache.java:2208)
    ... 37 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/script/ScriptEngineFactory
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:3134)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2285)
    at com.google.inject.spi.InjectionPoint.getInjectionPoints(InjectionPoint.java:688)
    at com.google.inject.spi.InjectionPoint.forInstanceMethodsAndFields(InjectionPoint.java:380)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorBindingImpl.getInternalDependencies(ConstructorBindingImpl.java:165)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getInternalDependencies(InjectorImpl.java:616)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.cleanup(InjectorImpl.java:572)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.initializeJitBinding(InjectorImpl.java:558)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.createJustInTimeBinding(InjectorImpl.java:887)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.createJustInTimeBindingRecursive(InjectorImpl.java:808)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getJustInTimeBinding(InjectorImpl.java:285)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getBindingOrThrow(InjectorImpl.java:217)
    at com.google.inject.internal.SingleFieldInjector.<init>(SingleFieldInjector.java:42)
    at com.google.inject.internal.MembersInjectorStore.getInjectors(MembersInjectorStore.java:131)
    at com.google.inject.internal.MembersInjectorStore.createWithListeners(MembersInjectorStore.java:98)
    at com.google.inject.internal.MembersInjectorStore.access$000(MembersInjectorStore.java:37)
    at com.google.inject.internal.MembersInjectorStore$1.create(MembersInjectorStore.java:45)
    at com.google.inject.internal.MembersInjectorStore$1.create(MembersInjectorStore.java:42)
    at com.google.inject.internal.FailableCache$1.load(FailableCache.java:37)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LoadingValueReference.loadFuture(LocalCache.java:3628)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.loadSync(LocalCache.java:2336)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.lockedGetOrLoad(LocalCache.java:2295)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.get(LocalCache.java:2208)
    ... 52 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.script.ScriptEngineFactory
    at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:466)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:553)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:486)
    ... 76 more
```

The failure comes down to

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/script/ScriptEngineFactory
```

but `--add-modules=java.se.ee` is supposed to expose that class so it can be found (and that seemingly works in Eclipse).

What could be wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems specific to my app. I noticed that it does shady things at startup: https://github.com/openrocket/openrocket/blob/master/swing/src/net/sf/openrocket/startup/jij/JarInJarStarter.java